# developing facebook applications with ruby: which gems to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

i am currently planning a facebook application to be developed with ruby on rails.
i stumbled upon the facebooker gem, but there seem to be other gems around as well - actually there is also a facebooker2 gem.

what are the current options i have with ruby on rails and facebook development? which gems are recommendable?

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook developers site lists some options for Rails along with samples. See http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Using_Ruby_on_Rails_with_Facebook_Platform

Comment: thanks - i know about this list. i wanted to get some real-life experiences from people that used the one or the other gem. some of the gems are outdated or forked.

Comment: Devenv, I've updated my answer above with my recent findings.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with this over the past couple of days.

The facebooker gem is written to use the old FB RESTful javascript API.

Facebooker2 is written to use the new javascript Open Graph API.  Facebooker2 depends upon the mogli gem.

I'm working with facebooker2 and hope to blog a tutorial once I've got it all worked out.

Here's my "tutorial".  I hope this helps.
http://blog.jonathanrwallace.com/2010/06/accessing-facebook%E2%80%99s-open-graph-from-within-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: hi and thanks for your comment! yes, please do blog a tutorial! this would be very helpful!